# How to show selected in dropdown in foreach while editing data

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using laravel framework. I am getting confused how to Show selected the dropdown data while editing some data here is my secenario:-
[image]

Here you can see the Monday are selected but i want to selected the First dropdown of monday and second dropdown of monday and same sa for tuesday.
Here is my code:-

```
enter code here
 <?php $from =array("6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23"); 
                        $days = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday");  ?> 
                    <?php  if(!empty($fitness['days'])){
                                $selectdays = explode(',', $fitness['days']);
                            } 
                            if(!empty($fitness['from'])){
                                $start = explode(',', $fitness['from']);
                                echo "<pre>"; print_r($start); die;
                            }
                            if(!empty($fitness['to'])){
                                $end = explode(',', $fitness['to']);
                                echo "<pre>"; print_r($start); die;
                            } 
                            ?>
 <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 fitness-time">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="additional">
            <div class="form-group">
                <span class="fitness-hours">
                    <h4>Opening Hours</h4>
                </span>
                <div>
                    <div class="info_user_detail">
                        <table class="table_info1 table-striped table-error">
                            @foreach($days as $key=> $alldays)
                            <?php if(!empty($fitness['days'])){
                                    if(in_array($alldays, $selectdays)){
                                        $checked = "checked";
                                    }else{
                                        $checked = "";
                                    }
                                }else{
                                        $checked = "";
                                    } ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="checkbox no-margin">
                                        <label>
                                        <input class="days" name="days[]" value="{{ $alldays }}" type="checkbox"  <?php echo $checked; ?>>{{ $alldays }}
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="time-class">
                                        <select name="from[]"class="select-class from">
                                            <option value="">Select</option>
                                            @foreach($from as $key=> $froms)
                                            <?php if($key <= 6 ){ 
                                                    if(in_array($froms,$start)){
                                                        $selected = "selected";
                                                    } else{
                                                        $selected = "";
                                                     } 
                                                } ?>
                                            <option value="{{ $froms }}" <?php echo $selected;?>> {{ $froms}}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="time-class">
                                        <select name="to[]"class="select-class to">
                                            <option value="">Select</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have used in_array but its not working. here is my Print data
[image]

I want to show when monday is selected 19 is selcted in first dropdown and
23 in second dropdown and same for tuesday. Please help me

Comment: Can you explain why you have `if($key <= 6 )` with your options? Also, is the print_r data you've provided for the `$fitness` array?

Comment: becuase $start array having 6 keys

Comment: Ok, but your using that on your `$from` array which has 18 keys. Also, is the print_r data you've provided for the `$fitness` array???

Comment: i have explode the from array at top look at that and please provide some answer so i can implement . I know i have doing something wrong . PLease Help !

Comment: Whoa! StackOverflow is not a place for you to come and just get other people to write your code for you. I am trying to help you but first I must understand what is going on with your code! No, you've used `explode` with the `$fitness['from']`, however, your `$from` array is  `"6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23"` and in one of your loops you're basically saying ignore me if I'm `"13"` or above.

Comment: just forget about ($key<=6 ) i  want first dropdown to be selected of mionday

Comment: That is the reason you're never going to see Monday being selected because 19 has a key of 13 and 23 has a key of 17.

Comment: so what can i do tell me :(